# Rimless toilets, and "not suitable for installation with flush valves"

Tags: toilet

We're looking to replace our old, cracked V&B Omnia Classic toilets with https://www.villeroy-boch.co.uk/bw/m/O.novo-Washdown-WC,-rimless--5660R0.html . The measurements of the important bits line up. Our old ones are not rimless, but these are. On the product page, it mentions:

`DirectFlush. Sanitary porcelain. Also available in CeramicPlus. not suitable for installation with flush valves.`

Does anybody know what "not suitable for installation with flush valves" means?

For what it's worth, our flush consists of:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00505EFFG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1 for the cistern

and

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0017VGWEO/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 for the flush panel.

Comment: I believe that means the commercial flush valves such as the kind you find in airport restrooms for tankless toilets

Comment: Another website shows the items as "not suitable to install with a flushometer". Looks like you're right. I'll call V&B in the morning to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So called V&B. The guy "simplified" the description, and stated that it's kind of been lost in translation; a lot of links on the English site even go to the German one. What not suitable for installation with flush valves means is that a cistern must be used that has a push button flush. He mentioned requiring high pressure, but that other flushing mechanisms using levers, direct mains, etc. will not work.

I mentioned our cistern does 3 / 6L for dual flush, and he mentioned that the installer can dial down the full flush to 4.5L, as that's all the Direct Flush systems need. A 6L shouldn't cause an issue as the V&B rimless flushes have a flat "rim" (well, they call it a ledge) that prevents splashing, and since water is released along the sides of the rim, extra water would merely be waste. Still recommended dialing it down to prevent water wastage.